# Can 'to' be omitted in the following sentence?

Tags: ellipsis

Can ***to*** be omitted in the following sentence? I think it can, but I can't find many examples on the Internet.

> Mark Twain said that it's easier to fool people than ***to convince***
>   them that they have been fooled.

Comment: Yes, when two infinitival clauses are linked by "than", the _to_ marker may be optionally omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "to" can be omitted.

The sentence is a parallel structure of the form "A [is easier than] B".  Both A and B should be in the same form ("to fool" and "to convince"), but it's a personal choice of style whether to include the repetitive second "to".

Another example:

> Warlord: Conan, what is best in life?
>   Conan: **To crush** your enemies, **see** them driven before you, and **to hear** the lamentations of their women! [source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PQ6335puOc)

Note the third "to" could also be omitted, but I guess the writer left it in to add a slight emphasis to Conan's third example of "what is best in life".  It's also not uncommon to add the word back in a long list:

> On Sundays I like **to get up** late, eat a large breakfast, take a long walk, read a good book, putter around my garden, and **to go** to my parents' house for dinner.